# How to Iterate a list and add a element into list with index

Tags: list, groovy

I am using below code to iterate `list` and to add element into `list with index`

```
hierhier.each() { k, v ->
    println 'k---------' + k
    if(k == 0){
    dataList += v
    println "dataList first ----------- " +  dataList
    }else{
        dataList.eachWithIndex {list,index-> // line no 2566
            if(dataList[index].get(primaryField) == k){
              //println "index---------" + dataList[index].get(index)
              int position = index
              println 'position--------- ' + ++position
              v.each {it ->
              //dataList[index] = v
              dataList.add(position,it)
              position++
              println "dataList----------- " + dataList
              }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

But its throwing error

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

While first time I mean for **first iterator its working fine** but the next iterator i.e. second iterator its not working. How can I resolve this issue with matching my requirement.

Output:

> Error |
> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>
> Error |
> com.acumetric.hrat.aggregator.yourService$_$tt__getDataForGrid_closure84$$EPWABwO5.doCall(DataImportService.groovy:2566)

Comment: @sharonbn He labelled the question with Java, and I believe Groovy runs on the JVM.  So this question is not unrelated to Java, and actually the problem he is facing precisely exists in Java as well when iterating over lists while also updating.

Comment: @sharonbn Sorry. I don't bother if I get solution with java was looking for fast solution

Comment: I know Groovy runs over jvm so is clojure and jython and about 100 more. i still dont see the relevance for java tag. imo, java tag is for java language. how can a java programmer that is unknowledable in groovy help here? i cnanot even convert this to java

Comment: Please guys don't down vote for proper question also

Comment: ok I edited question

Comment: Instead of using eachWithIndex, iterate using listIterator and set items using listIterator.add() method call.

Comment: Can you add the missing code so that is runnable? we can't see how hierhier, dataList, and primaryField are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The `eachWithIndex` method uses an `Iterator` which as you have found will not allow adding element.  Instead you can use a `ListIterator` from the `listIterator()` method on your colletion (`dataList`).  Most importantly it includes an `add` method.

I'm not quite understanding your logic concerning `v`, but the general idea would be something like this:

```
hierhier.each() { k, v ->
    if(k == 0){
        dataList += v
    } else {
        def iter = datalist.listIterator()

        // iterate though `dataList` as long as there is a next element
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            def list = iter.next()
            if(list[primaryField] == key){
                v.each {it ->
                    iter.add(it)
                }
            }
        } // while
    } // else
}
```

Comment: this is not gonna fulfill my requirement as I want to insert into particular postion

Comment: The `add` method on the `ListIterator` inserts at the current location within the process, it's not adding to the end of the `dataList`.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing your map during iteration, so *ConcurrentModificationException* is thrown.

If you sure that is the correct way you can **switch from a regular map** (hierhier is probably HashMap, right?) **to ConcurrentHashMap**.

Although be aware that is not safe to view and edit any collection at the same time. So you should probably rethink the whole process.